# Select option attribute returns Undefined with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<select class="form-control select-draw">
  <option data-image="20" value="1">Image A</option>
  <option data-image="21" value="2">Image B</option>
</select>
```

I'm trying to get the values for both the `value` and `data-image` attributes but only the `value` is returned and the value for `data-image` is `undefined`. I have tried to use both the `attr('data-image')` and the `data('image')`, both of which are returning undefined on alert. What am I doing wrong here?

```
$(".select-draw").change(function(){
  var val = $(this).val();
  var img = $(this).attr("data-image"); 
  alert(val); //Returns the correct value
  alert(img);  //Returns Undefined
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `find('option:selected')` to reference the selected option for which you need the `data-image` value.

```js
$(".select-draw").change(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  var img = $(this).find('option:selected').data("image");
  alert(val); //Returns the correct value
  alert(img); //Returns Undefined
  return;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control select-draw">
  <option data-image="20" value="1">Image A</option>
  <option data-image="21" value="2">Image B</option>
</select>
```

> You can also use `data('image')` instead of `attr('data-image')` to get the value of the `data` attribute

Comment: I see. But why does it work for `val()` and not the `data-image` or even `data()`?

Comment: @nTuply because that is how the `select` works. The `select` has `val` or `value` as a value of the selected option.

Comment: @nTuply because the value of `<select>` is automatically read from selected `<option>`, whereas any other property is only read from the `<select>`, if it exists. Not from `<option>`. They're different elements. Btw, Ankit: *"because that's how it works"* is not a very good explanation.

Comment: I see. Thanks so much. :)